# Deserializing legacy (binary) file after refactoring

Tags: c#, delegates, serialization

I'm attempting to re-organize my application's namespace hierarchy, so I'm using a `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder` sub-class to attempt to handle the renaming.  (Most of my renamed classes are correctly deserialized into their new namespaces without problems.)

The problem I have is that *one* of my serialized classes (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) failed to mark the `PropertyChanged` event as `[field:NonSerialized]` (oops), so legacy files are holding on to a reference to the legacy `Type` for that class (through the serialized delegate).

I've implemented `ISerializable` on the renamed class in an attempt to avoid deserializing the `PropertyChanged` event, but that doesn't appear to have worked--an attempt to instantiate the old (renamed) class still occurs.

How do I force the `BinaryFormatter` to avoid attempting to deserialize delegates?

Comment: If I deserialize an intermediate file, where PropertyChanged was marked as NonSerialized, the file is deserialized without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, it appears, was to implement `ISerializable` on the class containing the reference to the `Type`, and to manually manage which fields were serialized, and how.  This required that the refactored class leave a class stub in the original namespace for an intermediate build, in which we converted the legacy files to the new (refactored) format.  Backward-compatibility cannot be recovered, but we were able to salvage the offending files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why delegates CAN be declared OUTSIDE CLASSES.

Comment: This isn't very helpful.  I know that the PropertyChanged event should have been marked [NonSerialized].  It wasn't.  I'm asking, now, if there's anything I can do to avoid breaking backward-compatibility with the poorly-designed serialized file.